# Jquery Slider/Marquee - Mobile site?

Tags: jquery, mobile, jquery-mobile

Can anybody recommend a good cross browser approach/add-on to create a marquee slider for a mobile site which caters for varied resolutions?

I have 16 blocks to slide through, i would like to show 4 at a time and drag the slider across to see the next 4 etc so it will need to handle finger gestures - something like http://caroufredsel.frebsite.nl/ that can handle finger gestures would be ideal!

Cheers
Paul

Answer (score 1):

Try to use this: http://jquery.vostrel.cz/reel